# Understanding Command–query separation in python

Tags: python

I am learning the methods of list (difference between pop and remove)
and be aware of the [Command–query separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation#cite_note-1)

> It states that every method should either be a command that performs an action, or a query that returns data to the caller, but not both. In other words, **Asking a question should not change the answer.**[1] More formally, methods should return a value only if they are referentially transparent and hence possess no side effects.

I’m unable to interpret “Asking a question should not change the answer”,
I read the ppt 
wikipedia linked which takes an example of ‘light’ sign inside and outside of channel.
It did not illustrate the relationship between a question and an answer.

In my perception, It should be “**Answering** a question should not change the question”
that is reasonable to say

> In theoretical terms, this establishes a measure of sanity, whereby one can reason about a program's state without simultaneously modifying that state.

Does my deduction reasonable?

Comment: This seems to be a question more about English than about programming.

Answer (score 2):

The class below obeys to the CQS principle. Each of its method is either a query or a command. The method `get` provides information on the state and allows no side effects. The method `set` has side effects and thus returns `None`.

```
class IntValue:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = int(x)

    def get(self):
        return self.x

    def set(self, x):
        self.x = int(x)
```

In particular, the following will always be true.

```
v = IntValue(1)

v.get() == v.get() # Always True
```

Never will you have *asked* the value through the `get` method and changed it at the same time. Here, the CQS principle assures you that you can *ask* for the value multiple times in a row and still get the same *answer*.

The reason this is important is because a lot of undesired complexity in programs arises from side effects.

Now consider a similar class that encapsulates a list.

```
class ListValue:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = list(x)

    def get(self):
        return self.x

    def set(self, x):
        self.x = list(x)
```

The problem with the above is that asking a question may lead the answer to change.

```
v = ListValue([1, 2, 3])

lst = v.get() # [1, 2, 3]

lst.append(4)

v.get() # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

When developping large softwares, this is often a source of hard-to-track bugs. These can be avoided by making sure that you cannot access state from a `ListValue`, but only a view on that state.

```
class ListValue:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = list(x)

    def get(self):
        return deepcopy(self.x) # Here we return a copy of the list

    def set(self, x):
        self.x = list(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the gist of it. In computer science terms it pretty much means that getting information should not in any way modify the information

What they mean in

> More formally, methods should return a value only if they are referentially transparent and hence possess no side effects.

Has more to do with communication between your software and a client. This takes the above a bit further in saying that any information returned must be a copy of the actual stored value, and cannot be used to trace back to that value in any way.

Take this list for example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This is a very important list in my system, and clients pay me to give the access to my secret list. I'm going to make up a method here and say that the `send()` method will send this list to my clients.

If I `send(a)` to my clients, this breaks the tenet that is above. Because now my client can use the reference to a in a number of nasty says:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = None
```

Now when I try to access a, all I get is `[None, None, None, None, None]`. They were overwrite a because I sent them the reference and not the value. Instead, I should have `send(a[:])`, or a copy of a. Now regardless of what my client does with the list I sent him, it has no impact on what goes on inside my system.

Answer (score 0):

> I’m unable to interpret “Asking a question should not change the answer”,
>   I read the ppt wikipedia linked which takes an example of ‘light’ sign inside and outside of channel. It did not illustrate the relationship between a question and an answer.

`Light?` essentially asks "Is the light on?" It returns True or False.

The wrong thing for `Light?` to do is to turn the light on if it's off, or to turn the light off if it's on. In the absence of any other confounding code, executing `Light?` three times in a row should return the same value three times. *Asking a question should not change the answer.* But if asking the question `Light?` changed the answer, you'd get "True, False, True" or "False, True, False".

> In my perception, It should be “Answering a question should not change the question”

No, because answers (return values) *can't* change questions (method calls). But questions can change answers (if you code your methods that way).